# Riak - How to get the ID of the current item in a Map function

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, riak

Using Riak, how can I get the ID of the current item that's being processed in a Javascript map function?

```
function(v, kd, arg) {
    var element = v.values[0];
    var id = "??"; // How to get the ID of the current item
    return [id];
}
```

Comment: have you tried `this.id` or `element.id`?

Comment: `this.id` and `element.id` both return `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered how to do it:

```
function(v, kd, arg) {
    return [v.key];
}
```

I've found the source on: http://contrib.basho.com/get_keys.html